# Why is the output format from "Get file content using path" different for two different docs?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm using the action "Get file content using path" and I'm getting very different results for 2 different *.docx files which is causing problems when trying to use the output in a subsequent action.

In the one that's working properly, I get the expected output with "$content-type" and "$content" like so...

```
{
    "$content-type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    "$content": "UEsDBBQABgAIAA... blah blah blah"
}
```

In the one that's not working properly, I'm getting a result back, but the format is...

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Vary": "Origin",
        "X-SharePointHealthScore": "1",
        "X-MS-SPConnector": "1",
        "X-SP-SERVERSTATE": "ReadOnly=0",
        "DATASERVICEVERSION": "3.0",
        "SPClientServiceRequestDuration": "65",
        :
        "X-AspNet-Version": "4.0.30319",
        "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
        "Content-Length": "2670927",
        "Content-Type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        "Expires": "Wed, 22 Dec 2021 20:49:46 GMT",
        "Last-Modified": "Thu, 06 Jan 2022 20:49:46 GMT"
    },
    "body": {
        "$content-type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        "$content": "UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQAIz... blah blah blah"
}
```

The issue is caused by $content being a child of the body node.

Both are *.docx files. So, why the difference in the output?

Why would one include the status code, headers, and body and the other just contains "$content-type" and "$content"?

Comment: Can you post a print screen of you current flow? You should be able to read the child element of that json easily. Basically you can't change the way the API answer the json content, it's better to change the way you read the content.

Comment: Osfresia- I'm trying to read the returned JSON in either case and, if it has "headers" present go one path with the result. If not, go a different path. But I don't seem to be able to evaluate the returned JSON. i.e. if length(body('Get_file_content_using_path')?['headers']) gt 0. But it's always throwing an error or says the element isn't there

Comment: See if [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/JSON-Parse-Output-How-to-access-properites-from-Child-Object/td-p/189142) post may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

So, I achieved the desired outcome by using a formula like such ...

```
if(equals(variables('JSON')?['$content'], null), variables('JSON')?['body']?['$content'], variables('JSON')?['$content'])
```

[image: IV]

You just need to adapt the preceding actions to your own flow but this worked for me.

#### Basic Response

[image: Basic]

#### Extended Response

[image: Extended]